# How to get the property value of a combobox in a setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, orca, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have included a combobox replacing a textbox in a setup project using orca changing the property table, control table and including entries in combobox table. Now, I'm getting two comboboxes in my setup project but how do i get the value from the property to add it in a condition during installation?
Please guide me 
Thanks

Comment: You have the property name, so you use that in any place that conditions are allowed. So the issue is really where do want to use it as a condition? On a file being installed?  There aren't many places in a VS setup you use conditions, but if you're using Orca to change things you'll need to say where you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW I got how to do this